# How does the Google Analytics code run on Wix?

Tags: google-analytics, wix

Until recently, all the sites I've worked on have used the standard go to Google Analytics, copy the code, paste the code in a header file. But recently, a business acquaintance asked me about a problem with Google Analytics on her Wix site.

When I went to View Source to see if the code was even there, the only thing I could find was 
          var googleAnalytics = "UA-109642176";
So, I'm guessing that Wix has a different process, but I can't tell what it is.

I have two guesses:
1. The code is in the block of JavaScript with a lot of encryption.
2. They are running Google Analytics globally from the server.

It seems that the only channel to ask questions is to post on Facebook, which I did. The answer was a link to a page that doesn't say much.

Update: Part of the example I gave has an incorrect pattern for the Google Analytics code. This error is what set me to looking at the code for the Wix site (I don't generally work on Wix sites). But, the question is actually about the fact that the rest of the typical Google Analytics setup is missing and how does Wix run Google Analytics.

Comment: From memory, WIX just needs the GA tracking id and it gets put into a setting via their integration option for GA.
Did your friend use the Google Analytics integration option? Did they enter the full tracking id? Reason i ask is due to your example being in the format UA-XXXX rather than UA-XXXX-Y

Comment: I believe that there is an error in their tracking code, as you mentioned. That is the answer to their question to me, but tracking it down made me wonder how it works ... trying to "take a look under the hood" so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check that the tracking ID is entered correctly in the WIX provided settings option. 
The tracking ID is in the format UA-XXXXX-Y where XXXX is the GA Account No. and Y is the Property No. within the GA Account. 
If the tracking ID isnt entered correctly, they won't receive data in their GA reports.
If you find the full GA tracking id is entered in full correctly (also with no empty spaces before or after the entry) and it's not showing up correctly when you check the site with Google Tag Assistant, then it would suggest that the issue is at WIXs end, not the GA end of things (since WIX controls the integration of the tracking code on their platform).

Comment: Your comment helped me clarify my question. The fact that the code is wrong is important to my contact, but my question is about something you alluded to, namely, HOW does Wix control the integration of the tracking code on their platform.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by . HOW does Wix control the integration of the tracking code on their platform.?
If you were to say build a site yourself with HTML.. or php or similar..then you would have control over how the tracking code is added and configured on the site. 
That their integration only requires the relevant tracking id.. means they have control over how it is integrated..via whatever technology/method their platform uses

Comment: Usually, a site using Google Analytics has a script in the head tag with 4 JavaScript statements. In the  Wix sites I've checked there is only one statement which is a variable declaration with the ID. The other 3 statements are missing. My question is how does Wix send info to Google Analytics if they don't have the other three statements. I guessed that possibly, the rest of the script or a replacement script is somewhere.